# Can the word 'that' be a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, parts-of-speech, optional-that

Here are some example sentences:

1. The problem is that you are lazy.
2. The obvious disadvantage of this approach is that you have to know LaTeX.

In these sentences what part of speech is the word 'that'?

[One of the online tools](https://parts-of-speech.info/) identifies it as a preposition. How so?

[image: from online tool]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your online tool misidentifies the word "that."  In the sentences you provided, it should be a **subordinating conjunction.**

In the dictionary, there are entries for "that" as a *pronoun*, an *adverb*, a *determiner*, and as a *conjunction*.  There are no entries for its usage as a preposition, nor can I think of any such possibility in English.

Online tools are only as good as the programmers who have designed them.  Notably, there is a note that appears on that website under the color-coded sentence which reads:

> Computers make mistakes too!

That is a true statement.

The tricky part of your sentences is that the entire clause beginning with "that" becomes a noun which acts as a subjective complement to follow the linking verb "is."  This may confuse a grammatical dissection of the sentence that is not prepared for such a complication.

Comment: I have just noticed at the bottom!

Answer (score 1):

This is technically not a mistake of the algorithm—but [the website](https://parts-of-speech.info/) you used gives a misleading label. In the part-of-speech [tagset](http://surdeanu.cs.arizona.edu//mihai/teaching/ista555-fall13/readings/PennTreebankConstituents.html#Word) commonly used for English in computational linguistics, prepositions and subordinating conjunctions are grouped together. So the pink label here should say "preposition or subordinating conjunction". (If you try a sentence with "because" or "if" it should also be pink. These words are always subordinating conjunctions.)

https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy is a site that may give more helpful labels. It [distinguishes](https://universaldependencies.org/u/pos/index.html) `CCONJ` for coordinating conjunctions, `SCONJ` for subordinating conjunctions, and `ADP` for adpositions (prepositions). Note that different approaches to describing parts of speech will use slightly different sets of categories.

And yes, as has been pointed out, computers make mistakes sometimes. In general the accuracy of English part-of-speech taggers is high, but not 100%.